# Is com.google.code.bean-matchers a part of Hamcrest?

Tags: java, hamcrest

I 've found the project https://github.com/orien/bean-matchers which is called "Hamcrest matchers for testing Java beans"

But then why is it placed in 
   com.google.code.bean-matchers
   bean-matchers

I thought that Hamcrest is in
            org.hamcrest
            hamcrest-all

So is the first mentioned dependency really a part of Hamcrest?

Comment: It's a matcher for hamcrest, maybe?

Comment: They are Hamcrest matchers (as in implementing that API), they are just not part of the Hamcrest library...

Answer (score 4):

The matchers that belong to `bean-matchers` are Hamcrest matchers in the sense of [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relation: each 'bean matcher' is a 'Hamcrest matcher'.

For example, here https://github.com/orien/bean-matchers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/code/beanmatchers/AbstractBeanAccessorMatcher.java we see the following:

```
abstract class AbstractBeanAccessorMatcher<T> extends DiagnosingMatcher<T>
```

where `DiagnosticMatcher` resides in package `org.hamcrest`.

'bean matchers' were not included in Hamcrest because it is an **extension** and not a **part** of Hamcrest.